# How do you fry chicken, so that oil doesn't explode on your shirt?

Tags: chicken, meat, frying, frying-pan, chicken-breast

I love chicken, and I love to fry it. The problem is that the hot oil explodes, and it gets on my clothes.

I already have a cover for my pan. The problem is that I need to turn chicken upside down and then I need to open it. That's when I get the oil on my shirt.

What do you do? Are there any tricks?

Comment: Splatter guards or splatter screens? http://www.amazon.com/b?node=3737171

Comment: Don't just take the screen off and put it aside, use one hand to hold the screen in front of you and use the other hand to flip the chicken over, be sure to set the part closest to you down first so that the oil is pushed **away** from your body.

Comment: If all you're worried about is your shirt, get an old men's business shirt from a thrift store and call it you chicken frying shirt. Keep it in your kitchen with your aprons and wash it whenever you want.

Comment: I sometimes come late from work and want just to fry some chicken with my shirt. The lastly mentioned advice I am already using, but I was thinking that maybe there is something to do about this, because there is always risk to get some oil on the shirt. Maybe the oil and the pan have to be prepared in a special way, so that it doesn't explode while cooking?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a way to make the oil not pop. Sorry.

Comment: I'll wear an **apron** to keep oil off my clothes.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't moisture running from the underside of the lid? When the water drops hits the oil this happens. When flipping chicken over I hold the lid upside down and away from the pan. Then shake it off a bit before putting the lid back on the pan. But realistically there will always be enough moisture in the chicken to cause splattering. Maybe try turning the tempurature down a bit.

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46237/how-to-prevent-fat-splashes-when-i-fry-a-burger/ Also, see this question for explanation of the science of **why** it splatters: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46350/why-does-my-pan-always-splatter-when-i-make-chicken-breasts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a lid.

Spatter screens keep the oil mostly contained, while still allowing any moisture to escape.

A lid, on the other hand, collects the moisture on the underside of the lid.  When you go to lift it, the water drops back into the oil, and causes increased spattering.

You're actually better off without a lid, if you don't have a spatter screen.  Yes, you'll likely have to clean everything in the vicinity of the vessel of hot oil, but you don't have the problems associated with the lid.